# What to do if logfile has rotated?

Tags: java, algorithm, file

If I am continually parsing a log file and I detect that it has rotated, what is the best practice for handling this?

1. Update my internal hashmap to reflect a new filePointer (end of
   rotated file)
2. Or should I update the hashmap to 0 so it can read the
   rotated file from the start

My concern is that in the case of an anomaly in situation no. 2 mentioned above, I may indirectly parse a large file from the start and put significant load on the host.
However if I use no. 1 I may miss something critical that I was parsing the log file for.

This is the code that I've put together.

```
currentFilePointer = util.FileManagement.getLastFilePointerFromFile(file.getName());
lastFilePointer = Long.parseLong(lastReadFiles_.get(file.getName()).toString());

if (currentFilePointer < lastFilePointer) // file has grown
{
     processLineByLine(file.getName(), currentFilePointer, lastFilePointer);
} else if (currentFilePointer > lastFilePointer) // file has been rotated
{
     lastReadFiles_.put(file.getName(), currentFilePointer); // Option 1
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, I can't see any Hashmap... Hard to tell which solution is better :)

Here's a snippet of code I used to "tail" a file, which also supports rotates (to be run in a separate Thread):

```
@Override
public void start() {
    File file = ...
    long filePointer = 0;
    try {
        while (running) {
            Thread.sleep(updateInterval);
            long len = file.length();
            if (len < filePointer) {
                // File was rotated
                filePointer = 0;
            } else if (len > filePointer) {
                // File must have had something added to it!
                RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
                raf.seek(filePointer);

                // Here you can read the next lines using for example a BufferedReader

                filePointer = raf.getFilePointer();
                raf.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issues is how to manage log files in general. Such operations can be done using script language like bash or some general script language like python. An extensive tutorial for using java is [managing Logs for the Java Subsystems](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Certificate_System/8.1/html/Admin_Guide/java-logs.html).